# Converting 1 x 10-10 intp 1E-10

Tags: r

I have a column with 250 rows which I would like to change.

For example: 1 x 10-10 into 1E-10 or
3.51 x 10-16 into 3.51E-16

There are different P values in each column.

Answer (score 1):

Using evil parse:

```
sapply(chartr("x-", "*^", x), function(i) eval(parse(text = i)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] 1.00e+10 3.51e+16
```

Just noticed it is minus in power:

```
sapply(gsub("-", "^-", gsub("x", "*", x, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE), 
       function(i) eval(parse(text = i)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] 1.00e-10 3.51e-16
```

> If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
>   - Thomas Lumley, R-help (February 2005)

Comment: Evil parse seems menacing (just joking, +1).